# Search g_slist_find_custom() function in GLib

Tags: c, linux, glib

How to use `g_slist_find_custom()`, when im working with a single list.
And every node of list is a structure.

```
typedef struct {
  int number;
  int price;
  char* title;
}Books;

GSList *list    =NULL,
 g_slist_find_custom(list, /*?*/, (GCompareFunc)compp/*?*/);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find items in a `GSList` using a comparison function:

```
gint comp(gpointer pa, gpointer pb)
{
   const Books *a = pa, *b = pb;

   /* Compared by title */
   return strcmp(a->title, b->title);
}

GSList *list = NULL;
Books temp, *item, *abook = g_malloc(sizeof(Books));

strcpy(abook->title, "Don Quijote");
list = g_slist_append(list, abook);
/* more code */
temp.title = "Don Quijote";
item = g_slist_find_custom(list, &temp, (GCompareFunc)comp);
/* now item contains abook */
```

And you can compare constants using `NULL` as second parameter:

```
gint comp(gpointer p)
{
   const Books *x = p;

   return strcmp(x->title, "Don Quijote");
}

item = g_slist_find_custom(list, NULL, (GCompareFunc)comp);
```